# Open specific link in new tab on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

Previously, I got a solution from here on how to open another link automatically on page load. I got this code to do that

```
window.setTimeout(&quot;autoClick()&quot;, 2000); // 2 seconds delay

function autoClick() {
var linkPage = document.getElementById(&#39;dynLink&#39;).href;
window.location.href = linkPage;
}
</script>
```

**dynLink** is used in the body as **target="_blank"** within link tag. But this is loading the desired page within the same tab. Not in a New Tab.

I want when this auto page load clicks the link with id=dynLink, the page opens in a new tab then to load in the same tab.

### And I really means New TAB - NOT NEW WINDOW.

Looking forward to some working solution. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with your code so far? From what I know, there is no cross platform to open new tab by simulate click. The browsers are not like behavior like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 var newTab = window.open('http://google.at', '_blank');
 newTab.location;
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/70kdacL4/310/

For your specific case:

HTML:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.at" target="_blank">TestLink</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var link = document.getElementById("link").href;
        var newTab = window.open(link, '_blank');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Be careful if you use a popup blocker. A popup blocker can prevent the tab from beeing opened.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qm9ss6s4/4/

Comment: This will open only this link. I want the method like above through which I can open all those links with the ID dynLink placed anywhere on the page.

Comment: Yes, but you can combine your code with mine and that should work.

Answer (score 4):

Following are some of the solutions using plain `HTML` and `JavaScript`. You may use based on your requirement and share if you have any other solution.

Open Link **Immediately** on Page Load.

```
<body onload="window.open('https://www.google.com/');">
```

Open link in **New Tab** on page load.

```
<body onload="window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');">
```

**Refresh** the same URL Using `meta` tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
```

**Refresh** a different URL after `5` seconds Using `meta` tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL='https://www.google.com/'" />
```

Open different URL in **New Tab** using `meta` tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=javascript:window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');" />
```