# How to open a new tab with jQuery and window.open on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tried **window.open()** but it is not working:

```
<?php
    echo "<script>window.open('http://google.com');</script>";
?>
```

It is working only when i tried it with pressing **button** so please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open specific link in new tab on pageload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423689/open-specific-link-in-new-tab-on-pageload)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below on your php page.  To see that the code works here on stackoverflow, open developer tools in Chrome and hit run.  You will see the following message in console:
"Blocked opening 'http://www.google.com/' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set."

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var link = document.getElementById("linkToGoogle").href;
        var newTab = window.open(link, '_blank');
    }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="linkToGoogle" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Wait 5 seconds for this link to open by itself.</a>
```